Is there a word for things that people think are illegal but aren't?
I'm trying to describe an action people won't do because they are convinced it is illegal and there is a widespread belief that it is, yet it is not. I think there should be a word for it but I cannot come up with it. I'm preferably looking for a legal term but it doesn't have to be.
an example: _It is believed by many that corporal punishment is banned in all states in the US. But this is a _____: corporal punishment is permitted in the states of Alabama, Arizona, Arkansas, Colorado ....
-

To get the best answers, please edit to give an example sentence showing how the word would fit in.

Something that is taboo may not be illegal.

Do you have in mind the cases in which the people's belief that the actions are illegal is entirely irrational, or the cases in which the actions are close to what is actually illegal (so that they are understandably confused about the matter)?

Can you give examples of this kind of thing?

"common misconception" or "myth" are very general terms for a misbelief, but not specific to laws.

I am unclear as to whether you want the word for an action (.e.g. printing your own money, i.e. not copies of legal currency) or a name for the widespread belief that printing your own money is illegal. You need to edit to give an example sentence.

Such beliefs are commonly just called urban legends (as here), urban myths, etc. I doubt there's any more specific single word: lots of places calling them legal urban legends or similar, so if there is a single word, most people blogging about the law don't know it.

ilillegal perhaps

not in english, no. You'll need a phrase

the borrowed word "verboten" is sometimes used to indicate a "no go" type of action, but without really indicating why it is "no go".

There are many words for common but incorrect beliefs. I don't know of any that refer to ones specifically in the sphere of law, much less ones confined to this very specific pattern of erroneous belief in the field of law.

Thank you for all the comments. The concept of "legal urban legend" was particularly useful as I could find legal doctrine on the subject.

fallacy
noun [ C ]   formal
uk  /ˈfæl.ə.si/ us  /ˈfæl.ə.si/
an idea that a lot of people think is true but is false:
[ + that ] It is a common fallacy that women are worse drivers than men.

This is a far more general concept than what the OP is asking about.

I think you can use the term misconception:

a view or opinion that is incorrect because based on faulty thinking or understanding.

(Oxford Languages)

Strictly, 'misconception' applies too widely to qualify as an answer to this question, since it (a) can be individually held as well as widespread, and (b) it does not specify law.

This question poses an interesting problem, both inherently and because of the requirements of this site.
It is 'inherently' interesting because misconceptions about legal requirements are not uncommon. But it is difficult to see how, if the correct answer were, as I suspect, the answer is that, no, there is not, the task of finding evidence for the absence from the English of any word matching the descriptor is literally vanishingly small.  It would take a reading from cover to cover of something like the full sized Oxford (or Cambridge) English Dictionary or perhaps even every English Dictionary in existence.  There is no given starting letter (say 'l' for law and legislation or 'm' for misconception (suggested by user 6694).  Perhaps a search in a Thesaurus might help, if we could hit upon the right word. If enough people have been talking or writing about such misconceptions in a context that raises the chance of the needed extra word appearing in the entry  'law' or 'misconception'.
A third way might be to coin a word or two-word phrase.  The candidates are, I suppose, obvious and probably derived from Greek or Latin:

nomomythia (abstract noun); or (2) nomomythical or just 'nomomythic (adjectives)
The Latin is harder to find, since Latin lends itself less to compounding that go beyond the prepositional.

Perhaps we could in that case be allowed to search for a two-word phrase, like 'legal fallacy/misconception, the words so far quite reasonably offered, or even a hyphenated word, like 'non-law'.
